# How to mock patch flask request

Tags: python, flask, request, mocking

I have a Flask RestPlus resource :

```
def post(self) -> tuple:
    id = self._my_business.store_in_database(request.json)
    return {'id': id}, 201
```

Here is how i test it :

```
def test_post(self):
    request_mock = mock.MagicMock()
    request_mock.json = {'name': 'toto', 'owner': 'titi'}
    with mock.patch("sources.toto.my_resource.request", request_mock):
        self._my_business.store_in_database.return_value = 1
        response = self._my_resource.post()
    self.assertEqual(({'id', 1}, 201), response)
```

When I run the test I got the following error : `RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.`
Since I have mocked `request` I don't understand where is the problem. After printing `request` in the resource file it doesn't return my MagicMoc but a real `request`object.

Thanks for the replies and have a nice day !

Comment: I don't know why you would like to mock a request. You need to use a test client that will handle the context locals for you. Here is the documentation about it: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/testing/

Comment: what problem are trying to solve? did you try `test client`?

Comment: I want to simulate a request context with a mock. I don't want to make a real call to my API. I want to do a unit test of the method post.